# Rust a String like container which may contain arbitrary binary

Tags: rust, serialization

## Background Information

This question relates to `serde` and the output produced by Serializing and Deserializing Rust structs.

- My aim is to write a nested structure which serializes as a String, which is human readable.
- The sub-component of the main structure should itself be serialized in a variable way.
- If it is serialized using a human readable format, which serializes as a String, then the whole structure will be human readable.
- If the sub-component of the main structure is serialized with a binary format, then only the parts of the main structure will be human readable. The sub-components itself will not.

##### Strings

Rust `String`s have to be (should be) valid utf-8. (The rest of the standard library assumes that they are, so while using `from_utf8_unchecked` can create a `String` which isn't valid utf-8, this is probably not a good idea.)

##### Serializing as Json, or other formats

I am currently serializing and deserializing Rust structs in JSON format. This produces valid uft-8 formatted strings.

However, JSON is a temporary design choice, and it is likely the case that in the future this will be changed, most probably to Protobuf, or some other binary format such as Avro.

In this case, the output from serializing will no longer be valid utf-8. It is not a uft-8 string, but an arbitrary binary string.

What structure can be used to hold an arbitrary binary `String`? The most obvious choice would seem to be `vec<u8>`, however there are issues with this which I will describe below.

Another possible alternative might be `OsString`. However I am not sure if this is really the correct container to use. The name `OsString` doesn't quite imply the same level of generality as a name like `BinaryString` would, hence I am not totally clear about the intended purpose of this container, particularly given that `vec<u8>` exists.

## Results of Serializing and Deserializing with Serde

Serde provides two choices for serializing and deserializing. These are:

- `to_string` and `from_str`
- `to_vec` and `from_slice`

The following demonstration code shows the output produced by both of these:

```
use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;

use serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MessageBody {
    pub encoded_message_body: String,
    pub encoded_message_body_vec: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Message {
    pub message_body: MessageBody,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyType {
    pub my_data: i32,
}

fn main() {

    let my_type = MyType {
        my_data: 10,
    };
    
    // Encode as String using serde
    let encoded_my_type = serde_json::to_string(&my_type).unwrap();
    let encoded_my_type_vec = serde_json::to_vec(&my_type).unwrap();
    
    let message_body = MessageBody {
        encoded_message_body: encoded_my_type,
        encoded_message_body_vec: encoded_my_type_vec,
    };
    
    let message = Message {
        message_body: message_body,
    };
    
    //let encoded_message = serde_json::to_vec(&message).unwrap();
    let encoded_message = serde_json::to_string(&message).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:?}", encoded_message);
    
}
```

The output is shown below.

```
"{\"message_body\":{\"encoded_message_body\":\"{\\\"my_data\\\":10}\",\"encoded_message_body_vec\":[123,34,109,121,95,100,97,116,97,34,58,49,48,125]}}"
```

One output is human readable, the other is not. `encoded_message_body` is human readable. `encoded_message_body_vec` has serialized as a literal string representation of an array containing numerical values, which are themselves formatted as String. This is not human readable, despite the fact that the binary data in memory is a block of ASCII (utf-8) characters containing something which is formatted as a JSON string.

Please note: I have chosen to "display" the encoded message using `println!`. This data is actually being directed to Kafka. However, I could not write a MWE if Kafka is included. Exactly the same text is shown from a Kafka console consumer.

In line with the above information, I am aiming to produce something which looks more like this:

```
"{\"message_body\":{\"encoded_message_body\":\"{\\\"my_data\\\":10}\",\"encoded_message_body_vec\":{"my_data":10}}}"
```

## Summary

It appears that I am faced with a choice:

- arbitrary serialization format (JSON, Proto, or other) by storing the result in a `Vec<u8>`, but this is not human readable
- human readable output by storing the result in `String`, but this only supports encodings such as JSON which serialize to valid utf-8

Is it possible to have both human readable output, and arbitrary serialization format? Of course, for binary formats, the output will be a garbled string, and will not be human readable, but for formats such as JSON, it will maintain the human readability benefits.

Hopefully the question is clear? If not please ask further questions and I will try to clarify...

## Further Reflections

Someone else (offline) raised the point that we can't dump raw binary into a JSON formatted thing, because that binary will likely contain data (characters) which have special meaning to JSON decoders. (eg: `{`...)

This is a slightly different way of thinking about the problem, and it is a very good point to have raised.

- This means that if we want to have the outer message encoded with JSON (which we do) then the binary payload part must be encoded as something like base 64, or 85, etc...
- Someone else pointed this out in one of the answers too.

This pushes me towards thinking that we might not actually gain anything by changing the "payload" to a binary encoding, even if the payload is large, because this would inevitably require encoding and decoding through an additional layer.

```
[struct] <-> BinarySerializedData <-> BaseXXEncoded (String, `encoded_message_body`) 
    <-> JSON Encoded String <-> [Wire]
```

To understand the performance impact some tests would need to be run. It might make sense to do this, or it might not, possibly depending5 on the average size of binary payload.

Comment: Using JSON, you really can't allow it to contain arbitrary binary data. Sooner rather than later, you'd run into a situation where the binary is interpreted as `"`, `,`, or `}` which will obviously throw off parsers. For JSON, I recommend using base64 (base85 strings contain `"`, `'` as well as backslashes). If you absolutely do need to save **raw** binary data, don't use JSON.

Answer (score 2):

> `from_utf8_unchecked` can create a `String` which isn't valid utf-8, this is probably not a good idea

it's straight up immediate UB.

> What structure can be used to hold an arbitrary binary String? The most obvious choice would seem to be vec, however there are issues with this which I will describe below.

There is [`bstr`](https://docs.rs/bstr/latest/bstr/).

> Another possible alternative might be `OsString`. However I am not sure if this is really the correct container to use.

Absolutely not.

> Is it possible to have both human readable output, and arbitrary serialization format? Of course, for binary formats, the output will be a garbled string, and will not be human readable, but for formats such as JSON, it will maintain the human readability benefits.

There are basically two ways:

- an ascii-binary format, which can output the ASCII data directly and will manage the non-ascii e.g. bstr (I think) or a bespoke printer for `Vec<u8>`, however this may not be the best idea as the binary data may contain sequences which are interpreted by e.g. the terminal, leading to odd effects unless the printer takes that an account
- alternatively, smuggle the binary data into a normal string using a [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) e.g. base32, base64, base85, uuencode, ... this generally requires some framing but is a common method dating back to the origins of computing

Comment: The odd effects in terminal are actually probably ok, I anticipated this would likely occur

Answer (score 1):

I could fine nothing that supported that use-case in serde or other popular crates, but we can build our own!

A possible strategy is to use a wrapper around `Vec<u8>`, and serialize it like an array of strings and numbers, for each Unicode and non-Unicode chunk in the data. I will use the [`bstr`](https://docs.rs/bstr) crate for that, because it is suited for handling partially-UTF-8 data.

```rust
use bstr::{BString, ByteSlice};
use serde::ser::{Serialize, SerializeSeq, Serializer};

pub struct HumanReadableBStr(BString);

impl Serialize for HumanReadableBStr {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(None)?;
        for chunk in self.0.utf8_chunks() {
            if !chunk.valid().is_empty() {
                seq.serialize_element(chunk.valid())?;
            }
            if !chunk.invalid().is_empty() {
                seq.serialize_element(chunk.invalid())?;
            }
        }
        seq.end()
    }
}
```